# LateInitializationError: Field '_id@20301290' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying out creating a project in Flutter. I have created the models and using RethinkDB as the real time database. I'm writing a unit test for this simple project and kept on getting `LateInitializationError: Field '_id@20301290' has not been initialized.`. I have searched and viewed other related questions on SO and none I'd implemented resolved it.

Model

```
This is the user model
    class User {
      String get id => _id;
      late String username;
      late String photoUrl;
      late String _id;
      late bool active;
      late DateTime lastseen;
    
      User({ required this.username, required this.photoUrl, required this.active, required this.lastseen });
    
      toJson () => {
        'username': username,
        'photoUrl': photoUrl,
        'active': active,
        'lastseen': lastseen
      };
    
      factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json ) {
        final user = User(
            username: json['username'] as String,
            photoUrl: json['photoUrl'] as String,
            active: json['active'] as bool,
            lastseen: json['lastseen'] as DateTime,
        );
        user._id = json['id'];
        return user;
      }
    }
```

This is the REthinkDB connection class

```
import 'package:rethink_db_ns/rethink_db_ns.dart';

Future<void> createDb( RethinkDb rethinkdb, Connection connection ) async {
  try {
    await rethinkdb.dbCreate( 'test' ).run( connection ).catchError( (error) => {} );
    await rethinkdb.tableCreate( 'users' ).run( connection ).catchError( ( error ) => {} );
  } catch(e){
    print(e);
  }
}

Future<void> cleanDb( RethinkDb rethinkdb, Connection connection ) async {
  await rethinkdb.table( 'users' ).delete().run( connection );
}
```

This is the interface I'm implementing

```
import 'package:chat/src/io/christdoes/model/user.dart';

abstract class IUserInterface {
  Future<User> connect( User user );
  Future<List<User>> online();
  Future<void> disconnect( User user );
}
```

This is the implementation of interface

```
import 'package:chat/src/io/christdoes/model/user.dart';
import 'package:rethink_db_ns/rethink_db_ns.dart';

import 'interface/user_service.dart';


class UserService implements IUserInterface {
  final Connection connection;
  final RethinkDb rethinkdb;
  UserService( {required this.rethinkdb, required this.connection} );

  @override
  Future<User> connect(User user) async {
    var data = user.toJson();
    if ( user.id != null) data['id'] = user.id;
    final result = await rethinkdb.table('users').insert( data, {'conflict': 'update', 'return_changes': true,} ).run(connection);
    return User.fromJson(result['changes'].first['new_value']);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> disconnect(User user) async {
    await rethinkdb.table('users').update({'id': user.id, 'active': false, 'lastseen': DateTime.now()}).run(connection);
    connection.close();
  }

  @override
  Future<List<User>> online() async {
    Cursor cursorUsers = await rethinkdb.table('users').filter({'active': true}).run(connection);
    final userList = await cursorUsers.toList();
    return userList.map((item) => User.fromJson(item)).toList();
  }
}
```

This is my unit test for creating a user that returns error of LateInitializationError: Field '_id@20301290' has not been initialized.

```
import 'package:chat/src/io/christdoes/model/user.dart';
import 'package:chat/src/io/christdoes/service/user_service_impl.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:rethink_db_ns/rethink_db_ns.dart';
import 'helper.dart';

void main() {
  RethinkDb rethinkdb = RethinkDb();
  late Connection connection;
  late UserService userService;

  setUp(() async {
    connection = await rethinkdb.connect(db: 'test',host: 'localhost',port: 28016,user: 'admin',password: '',);
    await createDb(rethinkdb, connection);
    userService = UserService( rethinkdb: rethinkdb, connection: connection );
  });

  tearDown(() async {
    await cleanDb(rethinkdb, connection);
  });

  test('create a new user in the datavbase', () async {
    final user = User(username: 'username', photoUrl: 'photoUrl', active: true, lastseen: DateTime.now());
    final userWithId = await userService.connect(user);
    expect(userWithId.id, isNotEmpty);
  } );

  test('get online users', () async {
    final user = User(username: 'test', photoUrl: 'url', active: true, lastseen: DateTime.now());
    await userService.connect(user);
    final users = await userService.online();
    expect(users.length, 1);
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you ever try late convert to final?

Comment: Yes, I did by replacing the late with final, didn't

Comment: Okay, also can you convert setUp to setUpAll

Comment: Please read about [when to create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), esp. the part "As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible". I don't think each language element (LateInitializationError) should have its own tag.